# implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters

Tags: java, bit-shift

Please help me understand the For..Loop. How does the if statement work within the For loop statement. I'm specifically concerned with the if statement and how the following statement works:  `if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
checker |= (1 << val);`

```
/* Assumes only letters a through z. */
    public static boolean isUniqueChars(String str) {
        if (str.length() > 26) { // Only 26 characters
            return false;
        }
        int checker = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
            if ((checker & (1 << val)) > 0) return false;
            checker |= (1 << val);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation

Comment: `checker` is being treated as a vector of 26 Boolean variables.  `&` is a binary (or bit-wise) AND operation.  `|=` is a binary (bit-wise) OR assignment operation.

Comment: Thanks, AJNeufeld.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment under your post, the checker variable is used as a boolean of 26 values, one for each letter.

The following part converts the character into a decimal representation between 0 and 25 (26 possible values for 26 different letters)

```
int val = str.charAt(i) - 'a';
```

So 'a' becomes 0, 'b' becomes 1 and so on.

After that, if statement checks whether the following letter has already appeared before and does so by checking if the bit in the `checker` variable at the position of the letter's value `val` has already been set to 1 meaning the letter is already in the string.

Here is a little demonstration:

```
tet

t -> 116 - 97 = 19
e -> 101 - 97 = 4 
t -> 116 - 97 = 19

checker: 00000000000000000000000000

first iteration
   00000000000000000000000000 <- checker
 & 00000000000000000000000001 << 19
 ___________________________________

   00000000000000000000000000
 & 00000010000000000000000000
 ___________________________________
   00000000000000000000000000 = 0


second iteration
   00000010000000000000000000 <- checker
 & 00000000000000000000000001 << 4
 ___________________________________

   00000010000000000000000000
 & 00000000000000000000010000
 ___________________________________
   00000000000000000000000000 = 0


third iteration
   00000010000000000000010000 <- checker
 & 00000000000000000000000001 << 19
 ___________________________________

   00000010000000000000010000
 & 00000010000000000000000000
  ___________________________________
   00000010000000000000000000 = 524288 > 0
```

`<<`, `&` and `|` are bitwise operators. In your example, `<<` basically moves that `1` to the left and `&` checks if there is already a `1` at that spot. Of course those are the simplest explanations possible but that's what's happening in your example.

It's not in the example but before the end of each iteration, `checker` is updated so where the `1` had been set in the lower number, became set in the `checker`.

In the third iteration, since there is already a `1` at the spot being checked (that 1 was set in the first iteration), the result will contain `1` at that same position so the whole resulting number will be greater than zero, and that's actually being checked in the if statement. So if the number is greater than 0, it means `checker` has a `1` set at the position of the `val`.

You can find more useful information about bitwise operators even on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

As I have said, I simplified the problem as much as I could and this is just a general idea.

Comment: Great detail in your explanation Vlada903. I appreciate your prompt response in clarifying this problem.